# How to fetch url api "http://terriblytinytales.com/test.txt" in spring boot

Tags: spring, api, resttemplate

I am using Rest Template :- TO fetch The data

```
@RestController
public class apicontroller {
    @Autowired
    public RestTemplate restTemplate;
   
    @RequestMapping(value="/movies",method = RequestMethod.GET,consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    
    public List<Object> getobject(){

        Object[] movies=restTemplate.getForObject("http://terriblytinytales.com/test.txt",Object[].class);
        return Arrays.asList(movies);

    }


}
```

It is not fetching the data as its content type is text/plain
What should i do to change Content type here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text content can't be assigned to an array. Change `Object[]` to `String`.

```
String movies = restTemplate.getForObject("https://terriblytinytales.com/test.txt", String.class);
```